# How notification cleaner apps groups notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am making `notification cleaner app` which will block particular application notifications which are selected.

My question is, **How can we group other app notifications** like Clean master , Power clean and etc apps does.

[image]

I got this method which will work For *api>23,*

```
statusBarNotification.setOverrideGroupKey("MemoryCleaner");
```

But these apps works for api below 23.

> Is there any way to do this with *Notification Listener Service*? And is it possible to write/change other app notifications using *reflection method*?

Thanks in advance !!!